# How would I write a code for mentioning a role when a certain user mentions someone?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to add a code where the bot auto pings a role when another bot pings a specific user and I'm not sure how.

((in js))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We do not write your code for you. Please [edit] your question with an attempt and any errors/problems you may encounter. You can also look at the [ask] page for more information

Answer (score 1):

You should detect the bot's message in the `messageCreate` event and see who it's mentioning. If it's mentioning the specific user, you can send your message. Here is an example:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: ['Your Intents Here'] });

const roleId = 'The id of the role which should be mentioned';

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if(message.author.bot){ // If the author is a bot
        if(message.author.id === 'The user id of the bot'){
            if(message.mentions.members.get(`The id of the user who should be mentioned`)){
                message.channel.send({ content: `<@&${roleId}>` });
            }
        }
    }
});

client.login('Your Bot Token');
```

What this code does is when a message is being send by someone, it detects if it's a bot. If so, it checks if the bot's user id matches with the user id of the bot where you're looking for. If that's also the case, the bot will check if the message has a mention of a user with a certain user id. If the user is mentioned, the bot will send a message with only including a mention of the specified role.